# Fixed menu item

Tags: javascript, css

I have a scrollable dropdown menu and I want to keep the last item fixed and always visible on top while all the other items would scroll. However, with my solution it's really jumpy. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li class="fixed">Item 10</li> <!-- this item will be fixed and always on top -->
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
 this.$('.menu').on('scroll', function() {
      if (stickyItem = $('.fixed')) {

          //get the y position of the parent
          topHeight = stickyItem.parent().offset().top;
          //how far apart the sticky item should always be from the top of the bar
          heightDiff = stickyItem.parent().height() - stickyItem.height();
          if ((stickyItem.offset().top - topHeight) < heightDiff) {
            heightApply = heightDiff + ( heightDiff - (stickyItem.offset().top - stickyItem.parent().offset().top));
            stickyItem.css('top', (heightApply)+'px');
          }

        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
ul li.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: I agree. A jsfiddle would be much easier!

Comment: it seems to work fine, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested anywhere besides chrome, but here's a pure CSS solution for your problem:

```
html,body{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0}

ul {margin: 0; padding:0; height:auto;
/*this padding bottom allows the penultimate element to be displayed*/
padding-bottom:39px}

ul li {padding:10px; background:#eee; color:#333; 
font-family:sans-serif; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; }

ul li.fixed { /*you could also use the :last pseudo selector*/
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background:lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/patareco/kb99u78p/1/

Hope it does what you intended.